# UIPageViewController Transparency of Page

Tags: ios, objective-c, transparency, opacity, uipageviewcontroller

By default, while using UIPageViewController, the pages are a little transparent. This semi-transparency is visible when turning the page. Is there any way to make the page solid so that the page contents are not visible from the other side?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have `doubleSided` set to true/yes.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: The semi-transparency is due to the fact that `doubleSided` it is set to NO. If it is set to YES, the next page will show up on the back side.